# Changing position of InputToolBar in jsqMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

This question is similar to [#94](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/94) but I think I don't have any other option than changing the position of inputToolBar. I want to have smileys in place of keyboard and inputToolBar is at the position where it stays when keyboard is present. I did not tried to set constraint because I read the case [#94](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/94) and found that constraint is not working there.

Comment: I don't understand the question really. Are you trying to add the emoji keyboard or are you just trying to add a certain emoji as a button on the tool bar.

Comment: if a screen shot of what you are going for is possible that would help allot.

Comment: thanks for your reply :-), look this [1803](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1803)